# Elastic search synonym match involving numeric characters

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

I have documents indexed in elastic cluster with the below mapping. basically i have a field named model which holds car model names like "Silverado 2500HD", "Silverado 1500HD" "LX 350" etc etc.

```
POST /location-test-no-boost {
    "settings":{
        "analysis":{
            "analyzer":{
                "mysynonym":{
                    "tokenizer":"standard",
                    "filter":[
                        "standard","lowercase","stop","mysynonym"
                    ],
                    "ignore_case":true
                }
            },
            "filter":{
                "mysynonym":{
                    "type":"synonym",
                    "synonyms": [
                            "2500 HD=>2500HD",
                            "chevy silverado=>Silverado"
                        ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings":{
        "vehicles":{
            "properties":{
                "id":{
                    "type":"long",
                    "ignore_malformed":true
                },
                "model":{
                    "type":"String",
                    "index_analyzer": "standard",
                    "search_analyzer":"mysynonym"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The sample document content is

```
POST /location-test-no-boost/vehicles/10
{
  "model" : "Silverado 2500HD"
}
```

When i tried to search with Query string "Chevy sivlerado", the synonym matches perfectly to Silverado and gives back the result, on the contrary when i tried to search via query string "2500 HD" it is returning 0 results. I tried different combination on the Synonym involving number and found that elastic search synonym mapper does not support numbers is this correct?

is there any way i can make some mapping when user searches for "2500 HD", i can map the query to "2500HD"

Comment: You haven't said what you are using for querying. How do you do your queries? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's your problem:

- You try to define a filter that try to merge "2500 HD" into "2500HD" for searching
- But the analyzer will work like this:

  - Perform char_filter first (if any)
  - Perform tokenizer first, which is `standard` in your definition, hence "2500 HD" will be split into two terms `2500`, `HD`
  - Perform filters after that, which will transform terms into `2500`, `hd`. Your filter `synonyms` will be ignored because none of them matched the passed filter.

So when you query for "2500 HD", you actually search for `2500` and `hd`. And none of documents matched since the indexed terms is `2500hd`.

I prefer you to replace your `synonyms` with [word_delimiter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) filter, something like this:

```
"filter":{
        "my_delimiter":{
                "type":"word_delimiter",
                "preserve_original": true
        }
 }
```

It will transform your document `2500HD` into `2500hd`, `2500`, `hd`. And hence it will match the query "2500 HD", which will be transformed into `2500`, `hd`. Please refer the document link to find out more options.

You dont need to define a synonym filter like that. If you actually want to transform like your current definitions, let define another tokenizer instead of using `standard` tokenizer.

P/S: You can install inquisitor plugin to see how terms will be analyzed: https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor